# How to expand elements of an array into sub-arrays?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a huge array

```
huge = 1000
huge_array = (1..huge).to_a
```

How to best "expand" this array so that each element becomes a sub-array of format [original_element, "default value"], preferably in a memory-friendly way (without an explicit #map loop?)

```
expanded_huge_array = huge_array.some_magic
#=> [[1, "default value"],[2, "default value"], ... [1000, "default value"]]
```

Comment: What does `map` have to do with it? If you need an array filled with values then you need an array filled with values. Why have the array index (plus one) be in the array at all? Etc.

Comment: Always assume the question is a watered down, easy-to-ask and easy-to-answer version of a non-trivial problem. The actual "huge_array" people may have will contain anything but an index.

Comment: No, assume the question is complete, and provides enough information to answer it in the most reasonable way possible. If there are hidden criteria then it's difficult to reason about, and answers may not suit what your'e *actually* asking.

Comment: Good point about hidden criteria. However, I rarely miss a chance to slightly over-interpret a question to provide a better learning and problem-solving opportunity.

Comment: Right--and without actual context, you *can't* provide a better learning and problem-solving opportunity, because you don't know what's *really* being asked. You introduced criteria without any explanation (e.g., why no `map`? Both `map` and `zip` make new arrays, but in different ways. Both iterate over the original array, the `zip` answer creates a *new* array of the huge array's size *then* iterates, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
huge_array.zip(['default value'] * huge_array.size)
```

BTW, you might *simulate* this behaviour with [`Hash` with default](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Hash.html#method-c-new):

```
arr = Hash.new { |h, key| huge_array.include?(key) ? [key, 'default value'] : nil }
arr[1]
#⇒ [1, 'default value']
arr[10000]
#⇒ nil
```

Comment: Looks like #zip is the precision tool for this. Plus points for hash-with-block idea. (I wonder, what happens if such a hash is returned to a context where huge_array is not defined.)

Comment: No surprises, as the hash is called on an undefined key, the “local variable is not defined error” is raised.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`Array#product`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-product):

> Returns an array of all combinations of elements from all arrays.

```
>> [1,2,3].product(["a"])
=> [[1, "a"], [2, "a"], [3, "a"]]
```

Comment: > without an explicit #map loop?